# How to pass a variable as a string to locate a file to be read by d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, var, file-location

I want my code to look at the date, assign it as a variable, and pass the variables value as the name for the appropriate file location

I'm relatively new. My posted code is my current syntax attempt.

I realize that my function does not have enough arguments. Still trying to get a grasp on all this. any help is appreciated.

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]; 

var date = new Date();

d3.tsv("/Data/BlueForce1/`${date.getYear()}`/`${months[date.getMonth()]}`/2019.05.12.PT.txt);
```

Comment: My code is now a little more proper, but im getting depreciation errors when i try to run it in chrome.

  var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var date = new Date();

  d3.text("/Data/BlueForce1/`${date.getYear}`/`${months[date.getMonth()]}`/2019.05.12.PT.txt").get(function(error, data){console.log(data);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have so far...

```
"/Data/BlueForce1/`${date.getYear()}`/`${months[date.getMonth()]}`/2019.05.12.PT.txt
```

... is a strange mix of string with template literal, and it's not even valid (you forgot the closing quote).

You can do 2 things:

1. Concatenating the strings:

This is the easiest choice, just concatenate your strings:

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var date = new Date();

var url = "/Data/BlueForce1/" + date.getYear() + "/" + months[date.getMonth()] + "/2019.05.12.PT.txt";

console.log(url)
```

2. Template literal

For using a template literal, open and close everything with the back-ticks:

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var date = new Date();

var url = `/Data/BlueForce1/${date.getYear()}/${months[date.getMonth()]}/2019.05.12.PT.txt`;

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Yeah, It was end of day and i was leaving marks everywhere.

Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for!